# How to initialize a PDA mint in anchor

Tags: anchor, pda, token, mint

I'm looking to create a mint as PDA in anchor. In this case, the mint will be able to mint tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `init`  to initialize an account. In this case a `Mint` account.
- we provide the number of `decimals` we want and the `authority`. In this case, since it's a PDA. We can use it as the authority. That way the program can sign the transaction for the mint. (The mint can be used as a signer inside the program)
- provide `seeds` and `bump` for the PDA

```
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer,
        mint::decimals = 0,
        mint::authority = mint,
        seeds=[SEED_MINT],
        bump,
    )]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
```

**Example of Minting to a Token Account**

```
        let cpi_accounts = MintTo {
            mint: mint.to_account_info(),
            to: token_account.to_account_info(),
            authority: mint.to_account_info(),
        };
        let cpi_program = token_program.to_account_info();
        let seeds = &[
            SEED_MINT,
            &[bump],
        ];
        let signer = &[&seeds[..]];
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(cpi_program, cpi_accounts, signer);
        mint_to(cpi_ctx, 1)?;
```